# Custom database query with Sql for a specified user_id

Tags: sql, database

i've this tables:

```
Master
 id
 some-fields

Detail
 detail_id (counter)
 master_id 
 user_id (related to another tables)
```

I want to show all single record of master only for  a specified user_id.
The only approach i know ... multiply line for each detail ...

Thank you

Comment: answered like 1000 times here on stack overflow. use search before posting duplicates!

Comment: you're right Daniel, but how can search a question like this ? I don't know which terms using!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
FROM Master x 
INNER JOIN Detail y ON x.id=y.master_id 
WHERE y.user_id=?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
      Master.*
   from
      ( select distinct Dtl.Master_ID
           from Detail Dtl
           where Dtl.User_ID = TheIDYouWant ) PreQuery
      join Master 
         on PreQuery.Master_ID = Master.ID
```